# 1 user intermittently losing connect to outlook 2010 on SBS 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, outlook-2010

One of our clients has a problem with Outlook 2010. It connects when she opens Outlook, but then will lose connection for half an hour or  45 minutes and then it will reconnect. If they close Outlook and re open it, it works again!

Any advice on this?

Let me stress that this is only effecting one userout of approximately 20-30 users on the exact same setup.

The OS is Windows 7

Comment: Have you tried recreating her mail profile? It may be corrupted.